# How to execute Oracle Stored Procedure with 4 input parameter & more than 60 Output Parameter using SQL Worksheet in SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have created one SP Oracle 11g with 4 input parameter & approx 64 Output parameters all input & output parameters data type is VARCHAR2, I have Oracle Sql Developer Tool, When I execute Using GUI Controls the SP execute Properly & shows desirable Output 
When i try to execute the SP in worksheet by passing 4 input parameter in which 2 are date parameters, its shows error:

> Error report - ORA-06550: line 1, column 212: PLS-00306: wrong number
>   or types of arguments in call to 'TEST_PROC_PROFIT_N_LOSS' ORA-06550:
>   line 1, column 212: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

I try in worksheet

```
execute test_proc_profit_n_loss('01','01/04/2017','31/03/2018','01');
```

but I don't mention the OP parameter because of its more than 60

Comment: If your procedure has 4 input parameters and 64 output parameters you're going to have to specify all of them. Best of luck.

Comment: If you have 60 output parameters all of which are varchar2, why not put them into a custom table type with fields name & value, then just have one output parameter.  This would make your procedure a lot easier to maintain / debug.

Comment: @BobJarvis i try by specify all of OP parameter each line denoting Error report -
Unknown Command

Comment: @ShaunPeterson I am newbie, in PL/SQL hence not getting clear to your idea

Comment: Without actually seeing your code we're just guessing. Please edit your question using the `edit` button just below the question tags and add the procedure code, or at least the specification - procedure name and all the parameter definitions - and the code you're using to call the procedure. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @BobJarvis your suggestion work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code work for me

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
IP_USER_ID  VARCHAR2(200);
IP_FROM_DATE  VARCHAR2(200);
IP_TO_DATE  VARCHAR2(200);
IP_COMPANY_ID  VARCHAR2(200);

OP_COMPNAME VARCHAR2(200);
OP_COMPADD VARCHAR2(200);
OP_DE_GROUPNAME VARCHAR2(200);
OP_DE_FUNVAL VARCHAR2(200);
OP_DE_LEDGER_NAME VARCHAR2(200);
OP_DE_AMOUNT VARCHAR2(200);
OP_IMPCHRG_GROUP_NAME VARCHAR2(200);
OP_IMPCHRG_FUNVAL VARCHAR2(200);
OP_PURACC_NAME VARCHAR2(200);
OP_PURACC_AMOUNT VARCHAR2(200);
OP_SALES_GROUP_NAME VARCHAR2(200);
OP_SALES_AMOUNT VARCHAR2(200);
OP_INDIR_GROUPNAME VARCHAR2(200);
OP_INDIR_AMOUNT VARCHAR2(200);
OP_FINEXP_GROUPNAME VARCHAR2(200);
OP_FINEXP_AMOUNT VARCHAR2(200);
OP_INSUEXP_GROUPNAME VARCHAR2(200);
OP_INSUEXP_AMOUNT VARCHAR2(200);
OP_OFFEXP_GROUPNAME VARCHAR2(200);
OP_OFFEXP_AMOUNT VARCHAR2(200);
OP_SDE_GROUPNAME VARCHAR2(200);
OP_SDE_AMOUNT VARCHAR2(200);
OP_SATUEXP_GROUPNAME VARCHAR2(200);
OP_SATUEXP_AMOUNT VARCHAR2(200);
OP_ININCOM_GNAME VARCHAR2(200);
OP_ININCOM_AMT VARCHAR2(200);
OP_IC_LEDGNAME VARCHAR2(200);
OP_IC_LEDAMOUNT VARCHAR2(200);
OP_PA_LEDGNAME VARCHAR2(200);
OP_PA_LEDAMOUNT VARCHAR2(200);
OP_SA_LEDGNAME VARCHAR2(200);
OP_SA_LEDAMOUNT VARCHAR2(200);
OP_IE_LEDGNAME VARCHAR2(200);
OP_IE_LEDAMOUNT VARCHAR2(200);
OP_FE_LEDGNAME VARCHAR2(200);
OP_FE_LEDAMOUNT VARCHAR2(200);
OP_INS_LEDGNAME VARCHAR2(200);
OP_INS_LEDAMOUNT VARCHAR2(200);
OP_OE_LEDGNAME VARCHAR2(200);
OP_OE_LEDAMOUNT VARCHAR2(200);
OP_SDE_LEDGNAME VARCHAR2(200);
OP_SDE_LEDAMOUNT VARCHAR2(200);
OP_SE_LEDGNAME VARCHAR2(200);
OP_SE_LEDAMOUNT VARCHAR2(200);
OP_IND_LEDGNAME VARCHAR2(200);
OP_IND_LEDAMOUNT VARCHAR2(200);
OUT_OPENINGAMT VARCHAR2(200);
OUT_CLOSINGAMT VARCHAR2(200);
OP_GROSS_PRO_CO VARCHAR2(200);
OP_GROSS_PRO_BF VARCHAR2(200);
OP_GROSS_LOS_CO VARCHAR2(200);
OP_GROSS_LOS_BF VARCHAR2(200);
OP_GR_DIREXP_TOT VARCHAR2(200);
OP_GR_DIRINC_TOT VARCHAR2(200);
OP_GR_INDIREXP_TOT VARCHAR2(200);
OP_GR_INDIRINCOM_TOT VARCHAR2(200);
OP_NETPROFIT VARCHAR2(200);
OP_NETLOSS VARCHAR2(200);
OP_MSG VARCHAR2(200);
OP_RESULT VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
IP_USER_ID := '01';
IP_FROM_DATE := '01/04/2017';
IP_TO_DATE := '31/03/2018';
IP_COMPANY_ID := '01';

TEST_PROC_PROFIT_N_LOSS(

IP_USER_ID,
IP_FROM_DATE, 
IP_TO_DATE,
IP_COMPANY_ID,

OP_COMPNAME,
OP_COMPADD ,
OP_DE_GROUPNAME ,
OP_DE_FUNVAL ,
OP_DE_LEDGER_NAME ,
OP_DE_AMOUNT ,
OP_IMPCHRG_GROUP_NAME ,
OP_IMPCHRG_FUNVAL ,
OP_PURACC_NAME ,
OP_PURACC_AMOUNT ,
OP_SALES_GROUP_NAME ,
OP_SALES_AMOUNT ,
OP_INDIR_GROUPNAME ,
OP_INDIR_AMOUNT ,
OP_FINEXP_GROUPNAME ,
OP_FINEXP_AMOUNT ,
OP_INSUEXP_GROUPNAME ,
OP_INSUEXP_AMOUNT ,
OP_OFFEXP_GROUPNAME ,
OP_OFFEXP_AMOUNT ,
OP_SDE_GROUPNAME ,
OP_SDE_AMOUNT ,
OP_SATUEXP_GROUPNAME ,
OP_SATUEXP_AMOUNT ,
OP_ININCOM_GNAME ,
OP_ININCOM_AMT ,
OP_IC_LEDGNAME ,
OP_IC_LEDAMOUNT ,
OP_PA_LEDGNAME ,
OP_PA_LEDAMOUNT ,
OP_SA_LEDGNAME ,
OP_SA_LEDAMOUNT ,
OP_IE_LEDGNAME ,
OP_IE_LEDAMOUNT ,
OP_FE_LEDGNAME ,
OP_FE_LEDAMOUNT ,
OP_INS_LEDGNAME ,
OP_INS_LEDAMOUNT ,
OP_OE_LEDGNAME ,
OP_OE_LEDAMOUNT ,
OP_SDE_LEDGNAME ,
OP_SDE_LEDAMOUNT ,
OP_SE_LEDGNAME ,
OP_SE_LEDAMOUNT ,
OP_IND_LEDGNAME ,
OP_IND_LEDAMOUNT ,
OUT_OPENINGAMT ,
OUT_CLOSINGAMT ,
OP_GROSS_PRO_CO ,
OP_GROSS_PRO_BF ,
OP_GROSS_LOS_CO ,
OP_GROSS_LOS_BF ,
OP_GR_DIREXP_TOT ,
OP_GR_DIRINC_TOT ,
OP_GR_INDIREXP_TOT ,
OP_GR_INDIRINCOM_TOT ,
OP_NETPROFIT ,
OP_NETLOSS ,
OP_MSG ,
OP_RESULT 
);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(OP_COMPNAME);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(OP_COMPADD);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you said two of your input parameters are DATE, so try yo call your function this way:

```
execute test_proc_profit_n_loss('01',TO_DATE('01/04/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'),
TO_DATE('31/03/2018','DD/MM/YYYY'),'01');
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response I try your suggestion but the error can not resolve.